# Unable to complete request. Required unique key column values were not provided - Silverpop

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to add a contact to my database, the unique key is Email.

i am using this code:

```
public function addContact($list_id, $createdfrom, $columnslist,     $update_if_found = null, $contact_lists = null, $sync_fields = null){
    $xml = '';
    $xml.='<Envelope>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='<Body>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='<AddRecipient>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='<LIST_ID>'.$list_id.'</LIST_ID>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='<CREATED_FROM>'.$createdfrom.'</CREATED_FROM>'.PHP_EOL;
    if(isset($contact_lists)){
              $xml.='<UPDATE_IF_FOUND>'.$update_if_found.'</UPDATE_IF_FOUND>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    if(isset($contact_lists)){
        $xml.='<CONTACT_LISTS><CONTACT_LIST_ID>'.$contact_lists.'</CONTACT_LIST_ID></CONTACT_LISTS>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    if(isset($sync_fields)){
        $xml.='<SYNC_FIELDS>'.PHP_EOL.$this->getxml($sync_fields,'SYNC_FIELD').'</SYNC_FIELDS>'.PHP_EOL;    
    }
    $xml.=$this->getxml($columnslist,'COLUMN');    
    //$xml.='<KEY_COLUMNS><COLUMN><NAME>EMAIL</NAME></COLUMN></KEY_COLUMNS>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='</AddRecipient>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='</Body>'.PHP_EOL;
    $xml.='</Envelope>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($xml).'</pre>';
    $response = $this->request($xml);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
    return $data;
}
```

I double checked the database, i added  to specify the unique key, still i get error 211.
Thanks for the Help.

Edit:Sample output of getxml

```
<COLUMN>
    <NAME>
        EMAIL
    </NAME>
    <VALUE>
        name@domain.com
    </VALUE>
</COLUMN>
```

Comment: Where is `Email` in your xml ? Is it the commented line showing what is returned by your `getxml` ?

Comment: No, the get xml uses the parameter from the function to create xml tags from an input array, the output of the function was <COLUMN><NAME>EMAIL</NAME><VALUE>asdas@email.com</VALUE></COLUMN>

Comment: Ask the api server provider what error 211 means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because silverpop is not open about their api and error 211 means nothing without their documents.

Comment: error 211 means required unique key column values were not provided

Answer (score 0):

Make sure EMAIL is the ONLY key. If you use other database fields as keys also (multi-keyed), you will also need to include those in SYNC_FIELD tags. Also your commented  isn't valid, so leave those commented out.